# Are aria-labels translated in SharePoint

Tags: html, sharepoint

We are using SharePoint 2019 on premisse, in an english version with german language pack.

My question is, if the rendered HTML from SharePoint also translates the aria-label attribut, or does it stay in english?

**Update:**
We have following situation:
SharePoint 2019 Farm with 4 servers.
Installation language is English.
German language pack installed.

When we create a site collection (In German) based on a modern template (E.g. Communication Site or Teamsite modern), then some aria-labels are not translated. Likge the Gear-Icon or the Questionmark-Icon. The aria-labels for theese icon remain in English.
If we open create classic site collections the aria-labels are translated correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we found out, this is a bug at the moment (2020-09-15), and we reported it to Microsoft. According to Microsoft this will be fixed as soon as possible, as it affects all language packs.